# Spotify Playlist ios sdk swift issues

Tags: ios, swift, spotify, playlists

For some reason whenever I run the function get Spotify playlists, it returns that I have no playlists even though I have two. I was wondering what the issue was.
Thanks,
Richard

```
        SPTPlaylistList.playlists(forUser: auth?.clientID,     withAccessToken: auth!.session.accessToken , callback: {
        (error, results)->Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error!)
        } else {
            let hisplaylists = results as! SPTListPage
            print(hisplaylists)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Hey, your question needs to be improved a bit more. Add more code, tell us what you already tried doing and what was the result. How are you doing the authentication? are you sure you're not trying out with a test user thinking you are using a different user that has playlists? etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `auth?.session.canonicalUsername` instead of `auth?.clientID`